# BCM43142 WiFi adapter doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04, network-manager, broadcom

WiFi doesn't work and I'm getting "no WiFi adapter found" error.

Results of network info script:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 01 Sep 2020 14:55 +03 +0300

Booted last: 01 Sep 2020 00:00 +03 +0300

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:0866]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [11ad:6645]
    Kernel modules: wl

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b452 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD WebCam
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04ca:2009 Lite-On Technology Corp. BCM43142A0
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
6: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot enabled

##### lsmod #############################

cfg80211              704512  0
acer_wmi               24576  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 acer_wmi
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    32768  4 acer_wmi,wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  49152  3 acer_wmi,i915,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp1s0f1' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp1s0f1  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         702       1  0 Aug31 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0f1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp1s0f1' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.1/net/enp1s0f1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: Permission denied

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Riyadh (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp1s0f1  no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp1s0f1  Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     2369BA84B34843FE73A01F4
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.4.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        02:B6:04:06:D9:82:F4:38:95:E4:6F:84:9F:1D:B4:8E:C5:85:90:8B
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      11:09:20:94:BE:F4:40:A6:FA:D0:3E:51:A8:D4:D2:61:63:79:98:EB:
        10:58:65:0E:8E:46:FF:83:C3:09:4D:0D:4E:43:FF:34:22:F3:75:27:
        0C:0C:C2:CC:1D:94:31:F0:20:B9:61:67:C9:7C:B4:64:FD:F6:76:2F:
        90:66:77:66:E4:CD:48:E9:0A:AA:2D:4C:AB:65:64:6C:0E:B8:FE:80:
        29:21:79:61:2D:DE:8B:C2:7F:A5:6D:DD:B8:22:E7:4C:5E:DB:36:17:
        98:BE:79:AC:F2:32:15:A4:1A:A5:F3:7D:53:27:44:66:05:C1:4D:9E:
        B4:42:CF:CF:B6:D3:5E:76:51:CD:FE:49:CB:88:40:18:05:12:03:3B:
        C7:00:6A:E2:C2:67:CF:BD:42:FF:1D:7A:22:73:6B:13:85:1C:40:E3:
        2E:66:00:D2:99:A3:DC:1F:21:AB:2F:E4:DB:02:74:83:5B:6D:B7:AE:
        D8:35:05:4D:8F:99:27:08:8D:7A:C8:F3:E8:70:7B:B2:C3:0F:59:B6:
        4F:8F:F4:FE:02:1C:10:A5:60:27:F0:B4:9D:49:00:47:55:BB:14:73:
        4F:25:B1:41:AC:F3:E7:C7:C9:0E:3A:2A:B1:8E:81:B9:8D:29:C9:4E:
        58:BA:82:AC:EB:D2:EA:30:BB:90:F0:72:A4:38:8A:D2:81:65:1B:FB:
        D3:D8:C9:F5:41:3F:5B:9F:AB:76:C0:F4:3D:44:C1:B4:1D:7B:75:0B:
        C6:70:E0:E9:83:D8:33:A7:FE:DB:A0:B1:97:B1:12:26:F7:22:CB:99:
        A8:77:A3:EA:3A:DF:A8:8C:82:64:9F:5B:CD:34:E2:1F:79:09:03:C8:
        3B:F5:A7:20:CA:B2:8C:EF:C6:50:1F:A2:1F:11:21:91:50:6E:6F:A9:
        89:00:5C:4D:84:9D:07:09:BC:A9:2E:B5:F0:1E:BB:75:D7:8E:9C:20:
        8A:6F:40:DD:7E:40:54:38:09:A3:8B:C2:3C:7B:0A:0F:7E:7E:F3:86:
        33:CE:FF:D7:54:5F:89:E4:FE:BB:0F:A2:46:65:20:CE:CC:88:5B:53:
        CF:C9:AD:14:9C:FD:0C:6C:F2:A6:2E:DF:B0:E5:7D:A5:28:B1:9F:ED:
        12:31:4C:BD:DD:15:F3:A3:13:61:5A:FD:51:3C:7B:3F:5B:9F:D5:C9:
        74:B4:2B:F3:6D:6B:96:48:06:29:63:50:1C:6A:3F:F8:C5:43:D4:B1:
        A6:D8:00:1D:D8:A1:BF:B4:66:05:36:3A:E5:9F:BC:8E:F9:A4:F1:31:
        E1:8D:1C:DF:F5:27:19:95:38:73:DE:FF:D1:81:D5:B7:37:D2:B1:81:
        F9:0C:71:F5:5C:30:FF:47:DB:F2:A6:7D
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[ 5426.988330] r8169 0000:01:00.1 enp1s0f1: Link is Down
[ 7457.323889] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-04ca-2009.hcd failed with error -2
[ 7457.323893] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-04ca-2009.hcd not found
[ 7459.563934] r8169 0000:01:00.1 enp1s0f1: Link is Down

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note in your paste:

```
##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot enabled
```

In the most voted answer for Broadcom drivers, it says:

> NOTE In some computers, before performing the commands, you will need
> to deactivate the Secure Boot Options in your BIOS. This applies for
> cases, for example, where the bcmwl-kernel-source is already installed
> but the driver does not yet work. You can do a reinstall like so, or
> disable Secure Boot by going to your BIOS Setup:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

I suggest that you get an internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible and reinstall a perhaps presigned version of the driver as above. If this doesn't help, try disabling secure boot in your computers EFI/BIOS.

Comment: I was facing the same issue with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installation. This solution works for me.

Comment: @DinkarJain Which one? The package re-installation or the secure boot disabling?

Comment: disabling secure boot

Answer (score 0):

I had to go in the Bios and **disable Secure Boot first** (was **reset** for some reason) with F10.

Then `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` (no need for me).

The broadcom open source driver appears to be unsigned and is thus blocked by the UEFI secure boot process.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from @pushStack requires internet connection.
I fixed my internet connection with the package **bcmwl-kernel-source** in the installation ISO.
If you have no internet access you can refer to the official ubuntu documentation.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx
Install the packages **bcmwl-kernel-source** from a Terminal (in the commands below the install media is mounted at /cdrom

```
../pool/restricted/b/bcmwl

cd /cdrom/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source*
```