# Where can I find kernel blob for BCM43142?

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I've had a new motherboard installed in a machine with an existing Ubuntu 20.04 install.  The new motherboard includes a Broadcom BCM43142 WiFi adaptor.  I have the same symptoms described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271818/bcm43142-wifi-adapter-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-20-04), i.e. no WiFi and a "no WiFi adapter found" error message.  The accepted answer there involves a step `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`.  Unfortunately, my apt-get can find no such package.  I'm guessing I need to enable some additional repository.  Any idea what repository and how, please?

Comment: Try installing broadcom-sta-dkms instead

Comment: And, of course, you need a temporary alternative internet connection.

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks, but that gives "E: Unable to locate package broadcom-sta-dkms"

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yeah, I've cannibalized the ethernet cable that was running to my cable TV STB.

Comment: Open Software & Updates and make sure the repositories are enabled. Then run `sudo apt update` before trying to install packages.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'm guessing the repository I need to enable is the one labelled "proprietary drivers for devices".  Trying it now.

Comment: @ChanganAuto  And with that repository enabled, there's still no broadcom-sta-dkms, but there is a bcmwl-kernel-source, and it's done the job beautifully.  Do you want to write this sequence of steps up into an answer, or shall I?

Comment: Please do. There's a answer about generic Broadcom support already, one of the more frequent ones.

Comment: Having reviewed the accepted answer to the question of which this has been marked as a duplicate, I agree with the duplicate mark.   Thanks, everyone.